# XCode iOS multiple clones product

Tags: ios, xcode, target

We have a product where the project needs to be cloned multiple times and uploaded with custom designs and URLs. No major changes. The current plan is to clone the code, build it and upload. Can you guys think of anything better for each of the following:

1. Multiple targets is better than multiple source code clones?
2. Anyway to automate uploads?

Comment: Take a look at fastlane which automates a lot: https://fastlane.tools/ . For the custom designs I would try to go with multiple targets and #ifdef's. YMMV

Comment: Thank you for pointing!!